# Background changing when opening image

Tags: highslide

I'm working on this website http://www.tommasofettucciari.com/tela.html , as you can see it has 2 gray bands at the sides. When I opened one of the images in the gallery, the background texture fills the entire screen...how can I preserve the 2 gray bands when the image is opened? I tried to add a "width:" instruction in the .highslide-dimming part of the highslide.css file, but it doesn't works.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

.highslide-viewport-size class is used by "background" div, so you can try to fix left value and width percent.

Simple example

```
.highslide-viewport-size {
    left:50px!important;
    width:90%!important;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I didn't found the .highslide-viewport-size class in the highslide.css file, so I added it and specified a width value, but it doesn't work, and it also messed up the layout of the gallery...

Comment: To overwrite, you need to add !important declaration. See my updated answer, and paste it to your css. Obviously values should be adapted to your page.